# ag-grid autoSizeColumns only uses header and not rows content for resizing columns

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to auto resize each column to match the length of the columns content.

This is my code:

```
<AgGridReact
  onFirstDataRendered={(p) => {
    p.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(p.columnApi.getAllColumns());
  }}
  floatingFilter={true}
  defaultColDef={{
    sortable: true,
  }}
  enableColResize
  columnDefs={data.columnDefs}
  rowData={rowData}
/>
```

This is the result:

[image]

If I add `true` in this line, which is to skipHeader:

`p.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(p.columnApi.getAllColumns(), true);`

the result is this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the limited code, unless it is a timing issue, the following should solve it -

```
const allColumnIds = p.columnApi.getAllColumns().map((column) => column.colId);
p.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);
```

Try passing column ids to `autoSizeColumns`